# Failed to print what is stored in Iterator

Tags: c++, hashmap, hashtable, associative-array, unordered-map

```
// unordered_map::find
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string,double> mymap;
  mymap["mom"] = 5.4;
  mymap["dad"] = 6.1;
  mymap["bro"] = 5.9;

  std::string input;
  std::cout << "who? ";
  getline (std::cin,input);

  std::unordered_map<std::string,double>::const_iterator got = mymap.find (input);

**cout << mymap.find(input) <<endl;
cout << got <<endl;
cout << mymap.end() <<endl;**


  if ( got == mymap.end() )
    std::cout << "not found";
  else
    std::cout << got->first << " is " << got->second;

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Why when I tried to print the iterator got, and  mymap.find and also mymap.end will hapend to have errors.Why cant I print them out so I can know what actually they will return or what will be kept inside the interator got?

Error:

> Error 1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' (or there is
>   no acceptable
>   conversion)   c:\users\chunhaun\c++lessons\self-learning\self-learning\associative_container.cpp  19
>
> 6   IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these
>   operands  c:\users\chunhaun\c++lessons\self-learning\self-learning\associative_container.cpp  21

Comment: @C.Lang : Hi.I did put the (). As shown above.

Comment: Are you up-voting your own question and comments?

Comment: @ViteFalcon: you can't upvote your own stuff. I upvoted the comment because he properly edited the code.

Comment: @C.Lang: I'd only upvote comments or answers that adds value to a discussion. Here he did edit it, but I don't see why that upvote for fixing the error in his post. It's a personal preference anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot print the iterator because there's no function to print the contents of the iterator to an `std::ostream`. Same with `cout<<mymap.find<<endl;`, which tries to write the function pointer I believe. What you need to do instead is create a function like [this](http://ideone.com/8hduEr).

**IMPORTANT**: The operator overloaded function I've shown will throw exception when trying to print invalid iterator. **It is only to demonstrate** how to resolve that error for a 'real world' problem. The correct method to display contents of an iterator is how you've already done towards the end of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to print out not what is stored in the iterator, but the iterator itself. There is no `operator<<` defined to print out various iterators - what would they print? You can define one yourself if you'd like:

```
std::ostream& operator<<
(std::ostream& out, const std::unordered_map<std::string, double>::const_iterator& iter)
{
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, double>::const_iterator c_iterator;
    out << it->first << " with " << it->second << "\n"
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I'd also put the same warning as I have in my answer. This will throw and exception when dereferencing an invalid iterator.

Comment: @ViteFalcon Of course, one still needs to check against `end()` before using this. Dereferencing `end` will lead to undefined behaviour, but that goes without saying.

Comment: But with the map not being part of the operator it's not possible to do that check.

Comment: @Yuushi:I am still learning. I never learn thing like this "std::ostream& operator<<" is this from the operator chapter in  c++ ?

Comment: @JadenNg It's known as "operator overloading". When you call something like `std::cout << value` (for simplicity, let `value` be of type `int`), what is actually being called is `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const int i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it won't work as you are printing the iterator. You can do some debugging by first printing out the key/value pair of the map which you have created. Also it may happen that you are entering key value which is not in the map. You can verify this by displaying your input. This way you will be able to debug it more easily.
For getting input from user simply use

```
cin >> input;
```

Comment: Did you read the error in the post? It clearly says what the problem is.

Comment: The edit was made while i was posting my answer, yes simply printing iterator won't work.